# Index Slicing with Float64Index not working in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
             p12Diff
Pump Time           
3    -2.90 -0.000919
     -2.89 -0.000795
     -2.88 -0.000814
     -2.87 -0.000700
     -2.86 -0.000847
     -2.85 -0.000769
     -2.84 -0.000681
     -2.83 -0.000888
     -2.82 -0.000815
     -2.81 -0.000764
     -2.80 -0.000879
     -2.70 -0.000757
     -2.60 -0.000758
     -2.50 -0.000707
```

Oddly enough, when I slice with `idx=IndexSlice` for certain ranges, I get a `KeyError`, whereas for others it simply works. For example, `df.loc[idx[:,-2.90:-2.52],:]` cuts at -2.60, whereas `df.loc[idx[:,-2.90:-2.62],:]` raises `KeyError: -2.62`.

Might this be a bug?

Comment: what version pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed for 0.15.0 (RC1 is out now), see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/. 0.14.1 was a bit buggy with this type of indexing.

```
In [13]: df = DataFrame({'value' : np.arange(11)},index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1],np.linspace(-2.9,-2.3,11)]))

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
         value
1 -2.90      0
  -2.84      1
  -2.78      2
  -2.72      3
  -2.66      4
  -2.60      5
  -2.54      6
  -2.48      7
  -2.42      8
  -2.36      9
  -2.30     10

In [15]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [16]: df.loc[idx[:,-2.9:-2.42],]
Out[16]: 
         value
1 -2.90      0
  -2.84      1
  -2.78      2
  -2.72      3
  -2.66      4
  -2.60      5
  -2.54      6
  -2.48      7
  -2.42      8

In [17]: df.loc[idx[:,-2.9:-2.52],]
Out[17]: 
         value
1 -2.90      0
  -2.84      1
  -2.78      2
  -2.72      3
  -2.66      4
  -2.60      5
  -2.54      6

In [18]: df.loc[idx[:,-2.84:-2.52],]
Out[18]: 
         value
1 -2.84      1
  -2.78      2
  -2.72      3
  -2.66      4
  -2.60      5
  -2.54      6

In [19]: df.loc[idx[:,-2.85:-2.52],]
Out[19]: 
         value
1 -2.84      1
  -2.78      2
  -2.72      3
  -2.66      4
  -2.60      5
  -2.54      6
```